# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top hiding page content

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Okay first off I know there are a few similar questions out there and I've tried using them all but nothing seems to be working.

I've added a padding-top to the container of my main content, but when I put:

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
 body{
  padding: 0;
 }
}
```

it overrides the padding (even on computer browser) and hides the first 70px of the page.

Here is my current HTML:

```
<div id="navWrap">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="images/header.png" alt="" width="130px" /></a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <form class="navbar-form" role="search" method='post' action="phplib/search.php">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search Job..." name="srch-term" id="srch-term" value="" />
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </ul>


        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class='GeneralInfo dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>general info<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down navDown'></span></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
                    <li><a href='/email_list.php'>employee directory</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/docs.php'>documents</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/ftp.php'>ftp</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/manage/'>manage</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/flyspray'>bug/feature tracking</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='JobInfo dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>job info<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down navDown'></span></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
                    <li><a href='/job/list'>job list</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/files_required.php'>files rqrd</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/incoming_list.php'>incoming data list</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/signoff.php'>signoffs</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/leader_list2.php'>leader list</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/milestones'>milestone/timelines</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class='New dropdown'>
                <a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>new<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down navDown'></span></a>
                <ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>
                    <li><a href='/new_job.php'>new job</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/new_incoming.php'>new incoming</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/add_quoteset.php'>new quote</a></li>
                    <li><a href='/add_program.php'>new program</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
</div>
```

As you can tell I've added some of my own classes. If there's any CSS you'd like to see let me know.

Ideally, I would like it to work something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/J7jJh/1/show/

Where when a dropdown is clicked it pushes the content of the page down.

(I found that link during my search for help, it's not mine)

EDIT: This is a problem for viewing the page on MOBILE. Everything works fine on a PC. Mobile is the only issue, mainly landscape view

Comment: If you need it for mobile, you need `@media (max-width: 768px)`.

Comment: Actually it's max-width: 767px.

Comment: The fixed navigation fixes the navbar the static navbar pushes the content down, see the examples on GetBootstrap.com

Comment: I would suggest changing navbar-fixed-top to position: relative on mobile views.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Although that doesn't solve the problem with the nav covering the content of the page. All that does is remove the top padding on mobile, which covers the top content always and more content when the Nav is opened

Comment: @Christina I would make it static but I need the nav to be fixed top because there are some very long pages and it's just more practical to have it always there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want it to be fixed you can add a class to that `nav` (just in case you're reusing that `nav` anywhere) and then simply target it like this:

```
.myPseudoFixedNav{top:50px; left:5%; width:90%; background:#333;}
.mainbody{padding-top:100px;}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.myPseudoFixedNav{top:0px;}
.mainbody{padding-top:50px;}
}
```

See [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/lzY3WdrA3V)

The `container` part is added for demo purposes, but it's important for you to see how do you need to work it out in relation to paddings (you could also use `position -> top:100px`)

Comment: I'm not sure what this is changing exactly. I tried adding this (chanding someone of the values) and it didn't change anything really, I don't think.. PS: I can edit any of the bootstrap classes, this is the only thing I'm using this nav for. Thanks

Comment: it works EXACTLY as your link with desired behavior, only with different code, unless I'm not getting your question

Comment: ah, after re-reading your question I see yo don't want just the position, but also the pull-down nav. Let me see

Comment: Hm, well I mean it's positioned like the one in the link. But when I view it on mobile and expand the nav it just goes over the content still. I doesn't push the mainBody class down when the nav links are showing

Answer (score 0):

OK I think I see your concern.

When the caret (menu button) is pressed on the smaller resolutions the content **has** to be pushed down. This is only so the user can *see* the menu items.

Consider a 320px wide phone screen. They don't care about your page content while they are selecting a menu item as they can't see anything else other than the menu items.

Helpful?